# build for ipad simulation library and device library with cmake

Tags: ios, cmake

I try to build a static library with cmake for iPad simulation as well as iPad device. When the library is built, it will be put in a location that is determined by the built target (simulation or device). With cmake, I was wondering whether there is a variable that can tell the built target. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Xcode as generator?

Comment: @ruslo yes, and I am using xcode 4

Comment: I'm afraid that this is not possible. Usually you can get target location by `$<TARGET_FILE:tgt>` (see [add_custom_command](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command:add_custom_command)), but it's not working for `iphoneos`. Some other commands not working too, for example see this [bug](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=12506) for `install`. What is the end goal? Build universal library? Install library?